# ActiveX component can't create object (MATLAB Compiler)

Tags: matlab, excel, matlab-compiler, vba

I know there are similar questions out there, but this one is a little different (I think).

I used the MATLAB Compiler to convert a .m to an Excel add-in. When I run the add-in on my machine, it works just fine. When I send it to a colleague, they get the "ActiveX component can't create object" error. They have added the add-in no problem.

Is there something going on here that's easily fixed?

MATLAB code:

```
function mess = createAndRouteOrderWithStyle()

c = startbbrg();

[num,text] = exportToM();

s = emsx('//blp/emapisvc_beta');

order.EMSX_ORDER_TYPE = text(1);
order.EMSX_SIDE = text(2);
order.EMSX_TICKER = text(3);
order.EMSX_AMOUNT = int32(num(1));
%order.EMSX_LIMIT_PRICE = num(2);
order.EMSX_BROKER = text(4);
order.EMSX_HAND_INSTRUCTION = text(5);
order.EMSX_TIF = text(6);

events = createOrderAndRoute(s,order);

mess = events.ERROR_MESSAGE;

close(s);

end
```

Excel VBA code:

```
Sub GO()

Cells(10,10).Formula = "=createAndRouteOrderWithStyle()"

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the co-worker have the MCR installed?

Comment: No, they don't. Kinda seems obvious now. Thank you. I'll give that a go.